# Read file line of unknown size as string in VHDL

Tags: testing, vhdl, test-bench

I'm trying to make a Test Bench where a file of one single line, where posible characters are "1" and "0". I've to read them all, and use one by one as input in my DUT.

So, in my TB, I've defined a process like the following, in order to read the file an pass it values to my DUT.

```
stim_proc: process

 file input_file: TEXT is in "DatosEntrada.dat";
 
 variable rdline : LINE;
 variable line_content : string ( 1 to 4);
 variable readed_char : character;
 
 variable j : integer := 0;

begin       

 while not endfile(input_file) loop
   readline(input_file, rdline);
   --read(rdline, line_content);
   
   for j in 1 to rdline'length-1 loop
     readed_char := line_content(j);
     
     if (readed_char = '1') then
       input <= '1';
     else
       input <= '0'; 
     end if;
     
     wait for clk_period;
   end loop;
 end loop;
end process;
```

I'm reading the first (and only) line of my file with the first `readline` execution. After this, this loop shouldn't execute again.

Then, data from file should be inside `rdline`. So I've to process it. In order to do it, I've tried to loop over `rdline` length, but this loop doesn't execute.

```
for j in 1 to rdline'length-1 loop
```

So I thought I need to read this line in order to loop over it, and tried to move its data to a `string` var. The problem is that vector var like string need to have a defined size, and I *don't know the file line size*.

I've tried reading each time 4 chars from `rdline` into a string, process it, then repeat. However, I couldn't make it work.

I've found quite lot examples about reading files which have defined line formats, like columns or expected integers.

But how can I read an unknown text of one line?

Comment: If you only want one Readline call (to read a single line) just delete the outer loop. Then I suggest reporting what rdline'length and the actual text are, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `readed_char := line_content(j);` doesn't work when `line_content` isn't loaded. Otherwise your attempt to read values is basically sound.

The end of line is not contained in a read LINE buffer, there's no reason to not read the last character of rdline. An end of line is signaled by one or more format effectors other than horizontal tab, and  just the line contents are present.

There's also this inference that you have some relationship to a clock edge and not just a clock period. The following example shows that. Note you can also supply an offset from an edge using a `wait for time_value`.

A loop constant is declared in the loop statement. The variable `j` you declared is not the same `j` the loop uses. The loop statement hides the `j` in the outer declarative region (the variable declaration in the process statement).

Your code treats any other character in the string buffer than '1' as a '0'. I didn't change that, do demonstrate it. You should be aware of the impact.

A LINE is an allocated string of some length dependent on the length of a line in your read file. Every time you call readline the string rdline points to is updated.  It doesn't leak memory, the previous buffer rdline pointed to released.  You can read the length by using the 'RIGHT attribute or as in this case simply consume all the characters.

There may be line length limits in a VHDL tool implementation. There are none defined in the standard other than the maximum length of a string (POSITIVE'RIGHT).

An MCVE:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    signal input:           std_logic ;
    signal clk:             std_logic := '0';
    constant clk_period:    time := 10 ns;
begin
    
stim_proc: 
    process
        file input_file: TEXT is in "DatosEntrada.dat";
            variable rdline:    LINE;
            -- variable line_content : string ( 1 to 4);
            -- variable readed_char : character;
            -- variable j:         integer := 0;
    begin       
        while not endfile(input_file) loop
            readline(input_file, rdline);
            --read(rdline, line_content);
            -- for j in 1 to rdline'length - 1 loop -- EOL not in rdline
            for j in rdline'range loop
                -- readed_char := line_content(j);
                -- if readed_char = '1' then
                if rdline(j) = '1' then   -- changed
                    input <= '1';
                else
                    input <= '0'; 
                end if;
                -- wait for clk_period;  -- sync to edge instead
                wait until falling_edge(clk); -- input related to clk edge
            end loop;
        end loop;
        wait;     -- added prevents needless loops
    end process;
    
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 32 * clk_period then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
    
end architecture;
```

And for DatosEntrada.dat containing:

> 11011110001HELLO11230000

That produces:

[image: foo.png]

Where you can see all non '1' characters are interpreted as '0'.